# Django and mod_wsgi Root URL Config

Tags: python, django, mod-wsgi, django-urls

I'm having a very strange issue with serving a Django project using Apache and mod_wsgi. When the URL is requested it seems that mod_wsgi and Django completely ignores my ROOT_URLCONF directive and only uses the urls.py located in my application. However, when I run the pure Django web server it operates correctly.

This is my basic project structure:

```
├── myproject/
│   ├── config/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   └── urls.py <-- this is somehow ignored when run with mod_wsgi
├── myapp/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py <-- this is default when run with mod_wsgi
│   └── views.py
├── __init__.py
├── manage.py
└── wsgi.py
```

<s>**Edit**: Every .py file gets a corresponding .pyc file when the server is run **except** urls.py</s> - These are relics from running in development mode.

In settings.py:

```
ROOT_URLCONF = 'config.urls'
```

wsgi.py:

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "config.settings")
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Apache config (/etc/httpd/conf.d/myproject.conf):

```
WSGIScriptAlias /myproject /opt/django/myproject/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /opt/django/myproject
WSGIPassAuthorization Off

WSGISocketPrefix /var/lib/django/myproject
WSGIDaemonProcess myproject python-path=/opt/django/myproject processes=2 threads=8
WSGIProcessGroup myproject

<Directory /opt/django/myproject/>
<Files wsgi.py>
AuthType None
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Files>
</Directory>
```

<s>Furthermore, compiled bytecode is not generated for the urls.py file in my config directory. This makes it obvious its not even being touched by Django.</s>

Comment: Do you have `__init__.py` files inside `config`, `myapp` and `myproject`?

Comment: The Apache user will not have write access to the code file directories to create .pyc files.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton It seems to have access and all of the other .pyc files are generated correctly. Every .py file has a corresponding .pyc file **except** urls.py.

Comment: Does that mean that the code directories were made to be owned by the Apache user, or directories made world writable? It is not normally the case that the default Apache user could write to directories. Remove some of the other .pyc files and then rerun Apache and see if they get recreated. This will confirm whether the .pyc files are actually there because of the Django development server.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton You are exactly correct - those are relics from running the development server. Should've caught that... Thanks! Although I'm still not sure why its not abiding by the rules I set in config/urls.py